# Why is detailTextLabel not visible

Tags: objective-c

Here I will show you a snippet of the code, that i'm using:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *tableIdentifier=@"system";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[peoples objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[location objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Comment: Did you set the cell type to UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle ?

Answer (score 4):

The detailTextLabel is not displayed for cells with the UITableViewCellStyleDefault style. Init the UITableViewCell with UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle instead and you should see your detailTextLabel.

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
```

any below style can use as per requirement  :

```
UITableViewCellStyleValue1,     // Left aligned label on left and right aligned label on right with blue text

UITableViewCellStyleValue2,     // Right aligned label on left with blue text and left aligned label on right

UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle    // Left aligned label on top and left aligned label on bottom with gray text
```

Comment: Basically any of the options in the `UITableViewCellStyle` enum, _except_ `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` will show the detail text label.